Shopping cart, changing the number of products and Woocommerce blocks
The task is to send an event to analytics when the quantity of product in the product cart. It is not possible to use the standard woocommerce hooks, because woocommerce blocks are used. I've already broken my head, maybe tell me what can be done. I have already reached MutationObserver, but still the event does not fire(
function track_cart_quantity_change_js() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            console.log('track_cart_quantity_change_js loading');

            function initCartObserver() {
                var cartElement = document.querySelector('.wc-block-cart__main');
                if (cartElement) {
                    console.log('The bucket item is found, the observer starts');

                    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                            if (mutation.type === 'childList' || mutation.type === 'subtree') {
                                console.log('A change has been detected in the trash');
                                updateCartItems();
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    observer.observe(cartElement, {
                        childList: true,
                        subtree: true
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('The trash item was not found, we try again after 500 ms');
                    setTimeout(initCartObserver, 500);
                }
            }

            function updateCartItems() {
                $('.wc-block-cart-items__row').each(function() {
                    var $row = $(this);

                    var product_url = $row.find('.wc-block-components-product-name').attr('href');
                    var product_id = new URL(product_url).pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean).pop();
                    var product_name = $row.find('.wc-block-components-product-name').text().trim();
                    var product_quantity = parseInt($row.find('input.wc-block-components-quantity-selector__input').val());
                    var product_price = $row.find('.wc-block-cart-item__total .wc-block-formatted-money-amount').text().trim().replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '').replace(',', '.');

                    var product_brand = '';
                    var product_category = '';
                    var product_variant = $row.find('.wc-block-components-product-details__value').text().trim();

                    var productData = {
                        id: product_id,
                        name: product_name,
                        brand: product_brand,
                        category: product_category,
                        variant: product_variant,
                        quantity: product_quantity,
                        price: product_price
                    };

                    sendCartUpdateEvent(productData);
                });
            }

            function sendCartUpdateEvent(productData) {
                console.log('send:', productData);
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                dataLayer.push({
                    ecommerce: null
                });
                dataLayer.push({
                    'event': 'addToCart',
                    'ecommerce': {
                        'currencyCode': 'EUR',
                        'add': {
                            'products': [productData]
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            initCartObserver();

            $(document).on('change', '.wc-block-components-quantity-selector__input', function() {
                console.log('changed cart');
                updateCartItems();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'track_cart_quantity_change_js');


if MutationObserver in not work, there are same step you can take to solve that problem:

If card element is load:

The MutationObserver won't work if the .woocommerce-cart-form element isn't present at the time of its initialization. Ensure that the observer is set up after the cart form is fully loaded.
try:


var cartElement = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-cart-form');
if (cartElement) {
    console.log('Cart element found, initializing observer...');
    observer.observe(cartElement, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
} else {
    console.log('Cart element not found.');
}



Add a console log to verify that the cart element is being found and the observer is initialized

Debug the Observer Callback:

The issue might be within the observer’s callback function. Add console logs inside the callback to check if it's being triggered


var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log('Mutation observed:', mutations);
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList' || mutation.type === 'subtree') {
            console.log('Child list or subtree change detected');
            handleCartChange();
        }
    });
});




Alternative Approach - Manual Triggering:


If the MutationObserver is still not firing, consider manually triggering the event by listening to specific events like quantity change or DOM update.

Alternative Approach:

You can bind to the quantity change directly if possible:



$(document).on('change', '.qty', function() {
    console.log('Quantity changed');
    handleCartChange();
});




Check for Conflicts:


Sometimes, other scripts on the page might interfere with your observer or event handlers.
Test with other plugins or scripts disabled to rule out conflicts. Try isolating your script in a test environment.


Inspect the Timing of Events:


If the cart is being updated dynamically via AJAX or similar methods, ensure the MutationObserver is active at the right time.
Ensure the observer is set up after any potential AJAX calls that might dynamically render the cart.


Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. I was in a bit of a hurry and forgot that woocommerce blocks uses other classes. Now the script detects a table of products, but it still does not respond to a change in quantity.

ok! I will check what can i do
